# Tensorflow model outputs different value during inference

Tags: tensorflow, linear-regression, batch-normalization, tensorflow-estimator

During training, I'm logging the predicted values that my regressor model outputs against the training data. When I ran that same dataset on prediction mode, the range of values that the model outputs is way different:

#### Tensorboard

[image]

Here we see that the model has been predicting values in the range (140, 250).

#### Predictions against the same dataset

[image]

Here we have the model predicting values between (17, 23). What gives?

My suspicion is that the estimator API doesn't magically save the `moving_mean` and `moving_variance` when using `tf.layers.batch_normalization`.

#### My model:

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
  training = mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN
  extra_update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)

  x = tf.reshape(features, [-1, 32, 32, 3])
  x = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x, training=training, name='norm_128')

  i = 1
  for filters in [32, 64]:
    x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, filters=filters, kernel_size=3, activation=None, name='conv{}'.format(i))
    x = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x, training=training, name='norm{}'.format(i))
    x = tf.nn.relu(x, name='act{}'.format(i))
    i += 1

    x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, filters=filters * 2, kernel_size=3, strides=2, activation=None, name='pool{}'.format(i))
    x = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x, training=training, name='norm{}'.format(i))
    x = tf.nn.relu(x, name='act{}'.format(i))
    i += 1

  flat = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(x, scope='flatten')
  dropout = tf.layers.dropout(flat, rate=params['dropout_rate'], training=training, name='dropout')
  output_layer = tf.layers.dense(dropout, units=1, name='output_layer')

  predictions = tf.reshape(output_layer, [-1])

  predictions_dict = {
    'pred': predictions,
  }

  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, predictions=predictions_dict)

  loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=labels, predictions=predictions)

  tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)
  tf.summary.histogram('prediction', predictions)
  tf.summary.scalar('prediction', tf.reduce_mean(predictions))

  optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=params['learning_rate'])
  with tf.control_dependencies(extra_update_ops):
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss=loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
  eval_metric_ops = {
    'rmse_val': tf.metrics.root_mean_squared_error(labels=tf.cast(labels, tf.float32), predictions=predictions)
  }

  tf.summary.scalar('rmse_train', eval_metric_ops['rmse_val'][1])


  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode=mode, loss=loss, train_op=train_op, eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops)
```

Answer (score 0):

**__Edited__**

The only point of randomness in your code is `drop out`.After the train and at the prediction time, set the keep probability of drop out to `1`. Because the drop out layer selects the subset of variables passed to them randomly and training occurs upon this subset for preventing overfitting.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try that out, although the way I understood dropout is that you need to divide the activation by the  keep probability at inference time in order to compensate for the dropout effect during training (hence, you specify the `training` argument to `dropout` in the graph).